# ¿Como obtener datos de un gridView Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp

Tengo la presente asp:GridView la cual esta cargada desde ObjectDataSource. Deseo obtener los datos que se cargan en ella en el Code Behind para imprimir estos en una tabla pdf que se ejecuta al iniciar una acción en un asp:Button. Consejos y/o ayuda

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
   <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="nroAtencion" HeaderText="Nro Atencion" SortExpression="nroAtencion" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" SortExpression="nombre" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="aPaterno" HeaderText="A. Paterno" SortExpression="aPaterno" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="aMaterno" HeaderText="A. Materno" SortExpression="aMaterno" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="marca" HeaderText="Marca" SortExpression="marca" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="patenteVehiculo" HeaderText="Patente Vehiculo" SortExpression="patenteVehiculo" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="modelo" HeaderText="Modelo" SortExpression="modelo" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="nroChasis" HeaderText="NroChasis" SortExpression="nroChasis" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="nroMotor" HeaderText="NroMotor" SortExpression="nroMotor" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

```html
   
            string nombre, 
                   aPaterno, 
                   aMaterno, 
                   marca, 
                   patenteVehiculo, 
                   modelo, 
                   nroChasis, 
                   nroMotor;


            nombre = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text.ToString(); 
            aPaterno = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text.ToString(); 
            aMaterno = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text.ToString(); 
            marca = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Text.ToString();
            patenteVehiculo = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Text.ToString();
            modelo = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[6].Text.ToString();
            nroChasis = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[7].Text.ToString();
            nroMotor = this.GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[8].Text.ToString();
```